# Customize template symfony2 exception

Tags: php, exception, symfony, twig

I search in the forum and I not found nothing.

I have a problem with the exceptions handler on Symfony2. When I try to access a route that it not exists, Symfony retrieves a blank page (in prod environment). The log writes a message: Route not exists for.... but the custom template is not shown.

In config.yml:

```
twig: 
    exception_controller: twig.controller.exception:showAction
```

And the templates is in:

```
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error500.html.twig
app/Resources/TwigBundle/views/Exception/error404.html.twig
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I think that you don't need `exception_handler` since it's very advanced way of handling errors (when no other method fits needs). Just override those error pages (as you already have), clear the cache and you should be good to go...

Comment: Sorry, I meant `exception_controller` and **not** `exception_handler`